# Know if a button is pressed outer itself? (without a listener)

Tags: java, android

I'm adapting code from a Java application to work on Android, but the code uses the `Scanner` class and calls its functionality in many segments of code. Also, I have to implement it in a separate class from `MainActivity`.

So I passed the control that will display the data (a `TextView`) as an argument, and instead of using a `System.out.print()`, I do: `Salida.setText(Salida.getText().toString()+'new text');`

The main problem is the lecture (? sorry for my bad English) of code in cases like this, because `.nextLine()` does not work in this contect:

```
public static void main( String args[] ){
String line, cad;
int col, row, sz, i, j;
char ch; Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
line = in.nextLine();
    while(true){
        if( line.equals("*") )
            break;
        dir = line;
        cols = line.length();
        size = new int [cols];
        row=0;
        while(true){
            line = in.nextLine();
            ch = line.charAt(0);
            if( ch=='<' || ch== '>' || ch== '=' || ch== '*')
                break;
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,"&");
            for(col=0; st.hasMoreTokens();col++) {
                cad = st.nextToken();
                Mat[row][col] = cad;
                sz = cad.length();
                if(sz > size[col])
                    size[col] = sz;
            }
            row++;
        }
        print('@','-');
        printline(0);
        print('|','+');
        for(j=1; j<row; j++){printline(j);}
        print('@','-');}
}
```

I have done this:

```
public void Dibujar(){
String line="", cad;
int col, row, sz, i, j;
char ch; 
//Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
while(Leer.callOnClick()){
    line = Entrada.getText().toString();
}

    while(true){
        if( line.equals("*") )
            break;
        dir = line;
        cols = line.length();
        size = new int [cols];
        row=0;
        while(true){
            if(!Leer.callOnClick())
                break;
            line = Entrada.getText().toString();
            ch = line.charAt(0);
            if( ch=='<' || ch== '>' || ch== '=' || ch== '*')
                break;
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,"&");
            for(col=0; st.hasMoreTokens();col++) {
                cad = st.nextToken();
                Mat[row][col] = cad;
                sz = cad.length();
                if(sz > size[col])
                    size[col] = sz;
            }
            row++;
        }
        print('@','-');
        printline(0);
        print('|','+');
        for(j=1; j<row; j++){printline(j);}
        print('@','-');

    }
}
```

However, when I call it, it displays a blank activity...

`print()` and `printline()` are methods.

Comment: No worries about the English, but can you please clarify "the main problem is the lecture of code in cases like this"? I do not know what "lecture" should mean there.

Comment: the input of data, I want to introduce a series of string until '*' appears but with a EditText Instead of a Scanner. but the Scanner input is in a while loop... i have to wait when the user click on the button an then continue the loop.

Do you understand?... XD (is hard for me to explain it in another language)

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to restructure your code to do that. Scanner input and EditText input work in very different ways. There is no easy way to have a `while` loop that waits for GUI text input. GUI input elements are event based. So instead of having a loop that reads lines, you have to change your code so that each time the user clicks the button, just that one "line" of text is processed, and if that "line" starts with `><=*` (like in your loop), then the final processing happens. You have to get rid of the loop, break it up into separate pieces, and you'll have to use a listener.

Comment: thanks :D, I will try to restructure the code